# How to fix the size of a qt groupbox and align it on the top?

Tags: qt

Newbie here. I have a dock widget, and in it I created three groupbox, and using VBoxLayout for these three groupboxes. But the problem is when the window is maximized, the three groupboxes fill the whole dock widget and there a lots of large spacing inside of the items in the groupboxes. How can I keep the size of groupbox fixed and also as in the whole dock widget panel, keep them all aligned on the top?

What's the trick? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have to add a `QSpcerItem` but not directly :

> Normally, you don't need to use this class directly. Qt's built-in
>   layout managers provide the following functions for manipulating
>   empty space in layouts: ...

from Qt documentation : http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qspaceritem.html#details

you have to use :

```
myLayout->addStretch()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`QSpacerItem`](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7-snapshot/qspaceritem.html). For a vertical spacer use:

```
 QSpacerItem ( width, height, QSizePolicy::Minimum, QtGui.QSizePolicy::Expanding )
```

And for an horizontal:

```
 QSpacerItem ( width, height, QtGui.QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Minimum )
```